# Increasing Web.config size limit

Tags: iis-7.5

We are running up against some sort of size boundary on the Web.config file in our ASP.NET application. This appears to be 250KB. Is there any way to increase this limit?

**EDIT**
Sorry, fingers got confused typing.  250KB not 250MB :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agree with all the comments about looking really hard at the configuration stored in it, but if you even then need to do it, then you will need to set a registry key:

See: 
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB (REG_DWORD)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954864

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure web.config is the best place to store what you're storing?  You may want to consider moving your settings to a database.  I bet with a config file that large that the starting up for your app is huge!

If you need to extent it, consider a configSource to pull out your sessions.  If everything is in 1 section, it won't help much though.

Comment: Sorry, meant to type 250KB not 250MB. Our WCMS takes up a good portion of this. We also have a somewhat significant number of rewrites in here due to the fact that a lot of our URLs have changed since we converted to the WCMS.

Comment: 250KB is a lot more manageable.  For URL Rewrite, you can use configSource to have them in a separate file.  Here's how to do that: http://blogs.iis.net/ruslany/archive/2010/05/19/storing-url-rewrite-mappings-in-a-separate-file.aspx