# Web.Config size limit for Azure Websites

Tags: iis, asp.net, azure, web.config

I have an ASP.NET web application which I am migrating to Microsoft Azure. For various reasons, our web config file has grown to be rather large. On our "on site" instance, we have solved this by modifying a registry key as recommended in this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/180963/increasing-web-config-size-limit/182321#182321). We have also split our web.config into smaller files, but we now have sub files which have also exceeded the limit, so splitting the files is not an option anymore.

I am assuming this is not possible in an Azure Website, and only if I am running a Virtual Machine in Azure. Is there any solution to this without creating a virtual machine?

Comment: Could you re-architect your configuration logic to pull at least some of this information from a database rather than from a config file?

Comment: Unfortunately the excess file size is coming from IIS rewrite rules. Moving to a DB would require writing a custom rewriter

Comment: Does this not apply to the IIS setup you have? http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module